# how to insert image in database using phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

im develop website using xampp localhost. I want to add image using phpmyadmin but i can't add it..the image can display in phpmyadmin but can't appear on my website..is it any wrong with my coding in php?

```html
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="MMDB"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="artist"; // Table name 

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$Name=$_POST['Name']; 
$Hometown=$_POST['Hometown']; 
$Income=$_POST['Income'];
$Image=$_POST['Image'];
//file   =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$Video=$_POST['Video']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Name, Hometown, Income, Image, Video)
VALUES ('$Name', '$Hometown','$Income','$Image','$Video')";


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    include 'admin.php';
} else {
    echo "x";
}


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

---

whats the code for add image in folder?

// where should i insert this code ">
    $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    if ($image) {
             $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

```
         /* Ensure the file is JPG/PNG */
         if (($_FILES['image']['type'] != "image/jpg") && ($_FILES['image']['type'] != "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES['image']['type'] != "image/png")) { $error_status = 2; $error_message = "File uploaded was not a JPG or PNG file."; }  
         else {
           /* Ensure the file is less than 10MB */
           $size = filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
           if ($size > (MAX_SIZE * 1024)) { $error_status = 3; $error_message = "File uploaded needs to be less than 10MB."; }
           else {
             $extension = "jpg";
             if(($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/jpeg")) { $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile); }
             else if (($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/png")) { $extension = "png"; $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile); }
             $img_mime_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't save an image in your table.

You should create a folder to save uploaded pictures. In your upload process you copy the picture in the folder (use a hash to get a unique file name) then store the file name in the table.

When you want to use the picture, simply open the picture at filepath.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you should avoid storing images in mysql, however if you still want to do it then it's pretty simple:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="MMDB"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="artist"; // Table name 

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//BTW: always escape your data
$Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Name']); 
$Hometown=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Hometown']);
$Income=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Income']);
$Image=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$Video=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Video']); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Name, Hometown, Income, Image, Video)
VALUES ('$Name', '$Hometown','$Income','$Image','$Video')";


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    include 'admin.php';
} else {
    echo "x";
}


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Depending on the size of the data, your script may take a while to execute, not to mention the warnings others have posted.

**To save to a folder**

I believe the code you posted is probably to convert an image to a different format. this allows you to store to a folder:

```
$savePath = "/your/path"
if($_FILES['image']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       $error_status = 1;
       $error_message = "There was an error uploading the file";
}
/* Ensure the file is JPG/PNG */
elseif (($_FILES['image']['type'] != "image/jpg") && ($_FILES['image']['type'] != "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES['image']['type'] != "image/png")) { 
    $error_status = 2; 
    $error_message = "File uploaded was not a JPG or PNG file.";
}  
else {
   /* Ensure the file is less than 10MB */
   $size = filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
   if ($size > (MAX_SIZE * 1024)) {
       $error_status = 3;
       $error_message = "File uploaded needs to be less than 10MB.";
   }
   else {
      //Save the image to your specified directory
      $error_status = 0;
      $error_message = '';
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $savePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['image']['name']);
   }
}
//now the file should be uploaded, if error status is 0, then you can safely do this:
$Image = $savePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['image']['name'];
//and put that into the database "as text"
```

Comment: +1 for offering a solution to the question rather than just chastising the OP. While I agree that images shouldn't be stored in the database, if I desired/had to do so and came to SO to find out how, I'd want an answer

Answer (score 0):

you could **save the path of the image** in the database.

you could copy the image to the **folder**

while viewing the image.
you could **call the path of the image**

Answer (score 0):

Please don't save the image in the database. I know you can use blob but it will put very heavy stress on your database. Like the 2 answers above mine, it is better to save the image into a folder, save the path as TEXT into the database. Then call the image using